# Resetting the default Mediawiki configuration of apache2

Tags: apache, apache2, mediawiki, mediawiki-installation

I recently ran into an issue while working with two different .htaccess files in separate directories, along with the apache2.conf file located in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf, all at the same time. When I tried to check the changes on my website, it returned a 404 error no matter what I did. I tried to change the code back to the way it was before, but I ended up making the situation worse.

At this point, I'm wondering if there's a way to reset the mediawiki configuration of apache without losing all the skins, plugins, database, and LocalSettings.php configuration. Should I backup those items and then perform a fresh install, or is there a simpler way where I can see what is normally configured when installed (preferably the way it was or when freshly installed)?

I admit that I wasn't smart enough to backup my server, and this experience has taught me an invaluable lesson on the importance of backups. If anyone has any suggestions on how to resolve this issue, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you.